# Why is my bas64 encoded image creating a http request?

Tags: javascript, html, css, http, data-uri

I have encoded all the images in my css to base64 encoded data to reduce the number of http requests in the website. However, it appears that there is still an http request for the data encoded images as you can see below.[image]

I tried checking for a solution on the web but everywhere it says that there should be no http request for images which are encoded to base64. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: nothing. it's just there to see your resources.

Comment: Is that an img tag in your html or a background image in your css? Can we see some code?

Comment: It is a background image in my css

Comment: In that case, is there any way to check only the actualy http requests, without the data uri's being shown?

Answer (score 0):

It is not another request however it will show up in your assets.

Comment: It is marked as `(data)` in the HTTP status column. Not a request.

Comment: Is there any way of knowing the actual number of http requests?

Comment: In that case, is there any way to check only the actualy http requests, without the data uri's being shown?